# Can't save state of RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, parcelable, serializable, android-savedstate

I am making an application which has an activity where the user can add a picture to an object, here I give the user the choice between selecting a picture from the gallery or making a new one using the camera. Both of these options start an Intent which (after the user is done choosing a picture) returns to activity it came from.

But the problem I'm having is that when the user comes back sometimes some of the data of that activity is lost, so I "reload" it using a savedInstance. One of the objects I try to save is an arraylist of custom views that extend RelativeLayout. But when I load the data the following I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sition.projectmanager/com.example.sition.projectmanager.activities.ObjectActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.sition.projectmanager.TabButton)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.sition.projectmanager.TabButton)
           at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2144)
           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
           at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
           at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
           at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
           at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1173)
           at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:930)
           at com.example.sition.projectmanager.activities.ObjectActivity.onCreate(ObjectActivity.java:102)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: android.widget.RelativeLayout; IllegalAccessException
           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:692)
           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:653)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
           at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2142)
           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016) 
           at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235) 
           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655) 
           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986) 
           at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226) 
           at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 
           at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1173) 
           at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:930) 
           at com.example.sition.projectmanager.activities.ObjectActivity.onCreate(ObjectActivity.java:102) 
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326) 
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my custom RelativeLayout Class:

```
public class TabButton extends RelativeLayout implements Serializable {
    public TabButton(Context context) {
         super(context);
    }

    public TabButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TabButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And my onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putSerializable("CURRENT_OBJECT",currentObject);
    outState.putSerializable("TAB_BUTTONS", tabButtons);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentObject = (Objectable) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("CURRENT_OBJECT");
    tabButtons = (ArrayList<TabButton>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("TAB_BUTTONS");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept is wrong: You should not save entire widgets, but the information to **recreate** them.

> However, your activity might have more state information that you'd
>   like to restore, such as member variables that track the user's
>   progress in the activity.

from: [Android Activity Lifecycle, Android SDK Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

So save information as ints (in your example for identifying the selected tab) or other primitives and set in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: Thank you, I was already doubting the method I was using, but the way you suggested makes much more sense.